# Spring boot + security 3.0 expose public services

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to figure out how we may secure applications with spring boot.

I have a very basic HelloWorld Controller, with a services is supposed to be called only by authenticated users, and one that may be called by anyone :

```
@RestController 
public class HelloWorldController {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/private")
    public Map<String, Object> securedResource() {
        logger.info("Called : HelloWorldController/private");
        
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello collection's Private World");
        return model;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/public")
    public Map<String, Object> publicResource() {
        logger.info("Called : HelloWorldController/public");
        
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("content", "You well got public resource.");
        return model;
    }
}
```

For managing my authorizations, I tried to configure it :

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http)  throws Exception {
        http
            // Beware : order of request matchers is important.
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                // Specify that requests on "/public" services's pattern may be called by anyone.
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public").permitAll()
                // Specify that requests on "/private" services's pattern may be called by any authenticated user.
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/private").authenticated()
                // Specify that any other requests are not allowed by anyone.
                .anyRequest().denyAll())
            .httpBasic();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I though doing so will allow unauthenticated users to call the "/public" service. But when I call "http://localhost:8080/public" from postman, I get a 401 error, and it work only if I provide credentials in Basic Auth when I call the service.

Perhaps have I done something wrong ?

Edit : Below are some logs when calling the service

```
2023-01-25T19:25:11.888+01:00  INFO 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-25T19:25:11.888+01:00  INFO 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-25T19:25:11.889+01:00  INFO 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-01-25T19:25:11.895+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@8adba4e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@37348e64, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@44ab0b55, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@26490443, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6c3ee96d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6b97305f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@36d829c6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3894a5e1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@56ebb12, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@44bf732c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@44ef0221, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@18a1c2ab, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4390a01d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2bb41cea, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2aaea4a6]] (1/1)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.896+01:00 DEBUG 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /public
2023-01-25T19:25:11.897+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.897+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.899+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.900+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.901+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.902+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.902+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.902+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.903+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.903+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.905+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (8/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.905+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (9/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.907+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.909+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (10/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.911+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header
2023-01-25T19:25:11.912+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (11/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.913+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-01-25T19:25:11.914+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (12/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.915+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (13/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.916+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (14/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.916+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (15/15)
2023-01-25T19:25:11.917+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@843dacb]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.917+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@843dacb] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@5dd1b7b8
2023-01-25T19:25:11.918+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-01-25T19:25:11.918+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.919+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.921+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-01-25T19:25:11.921+01:00 TRACE 2352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:188) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: At first, it seems that everything is fine. Please add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and paste the output in the question.

Comment: Did you add `@EnableWebSecurity`  and `@Configuration` to your `SecurityConfiguration` class?

Comment: If you have the @Configuration on the SecurityConfig it should work, it works perfectly on my machine.. If you have more set up details please share... With above we wont be able to replicate the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I effectively forgot @Configuration annotation on my security configuration class. With it, it works as expected.

Thank you all.